# HTMLPurifier doesn't work properly with Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, htmlpurifier

I try to integrate HTML purifier with Laravel(https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier).

Doing as documentation, here is config file purifier.php

```
return array(
"settings" => array(
    "HTML.Allowed" => "div,p[align|style],strong,a[href|title|mailto],em,table[class|width|cellpadding],td,tr,h3,h4,h5,hr,br,u,ul,ol,li,img[src|width|height|alt|class],span[class|style],strike,sup,sub,code",
    "HTML.SafeIframe" => 'true',
    "URI.SafeIframeRegexp" => "%^(http://|https://|//)(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)%",
),
```

);

In this config, I try to allow H3, H4, but they are always stripped.
I am using PHP 5.5.4

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer myself. I have to load config and initiate it with Purifier::clean as below:

```
$purifier_config = Config::get('purifier.settings');
$content = Purifier::clean($content, $purifier_config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively this seems to work (ref https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier/blob/master/src/Mews/Purifier/Purifier.php#L81)

```
return array(
    "default" => array(
        "settings" => array(
            "HTML.Allowed" => "div,p[align|style],strong,a[href|title|mailto],em,table[class|width|cellpadding],td,tr,h3,h4,h5,hr,br,u,ul,ol,li,img[src|width|height|alt|class],span[class|style],strike,sup,sub,code",
            "HTML.SafeIframe" => 'true',
            "URI.SafeIframeRegexp" => "%^(http://|https://|//)(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)%",
        ),
    ),
);
```